# How to access Azure shared folder on file storage from WinCE 6.5 Handheld

Tags: azure, windows-ce, handheld

There is any way to access Azure shared folder on file storage from WinCE 6.5 Handheld I try to access by Network Plugin from Handheld but I have gotten pop massage Map Drive failed

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge: You can use Azure file shares on a Windows installation that is running either in an Azure VM or on-premises. The following table illustrates which OS versions support accessing file shares in which environment:
[image]

For more details, refer “[Use an Azure file share with Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-windows)”.